# Disable return key in TextInput React native

Tags: react-native, textinput

I'm using React Native's TextInput. I want to disable return key as per the requirement. Is there any way to disable/enable return key by custom code?
I tried with enablesReturnKeyAutomatically but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can, by using the `onSubmitEditing` props for `TextInput`. Posting sample here:

```html
<TextInput                   
  value={password}   
  returnKeyType="done"  
  onSubmitEditing={() => {
      if (password != '') {
          onLoginPressed();
      }    
  }}    
  placeholder="Password"    
  sub_place="PASSWORD"                     
  onChangeText={value => setPassword(value)}                     
  blurOnSubmit={false}    
  ref={passwordFocus}   
/>
```

Comment: Can you review the indentation? Your original code was really hard to read. I've improved the indentation to aid in that. But as I don't do much work in React Native, I'm not familiar with the established standards for indenting inline function definitions.